# Add textboxes in last row of gridview

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, gridview, datagrid

I am working on Windows Form app using C#. I have a gridview on my form that will contain 5 columns for Sr No, Item Name, Item Price, Item Qty and Item Amount. I want to have a set of five textboxes in the last row of my gridview so that I can enter my required values there and then upon entering the last value, the wholw row comprising of all the five items should get added to the gridview and again the last row should contains that set of textboxes for a newer entry. How can I achieve this?

Also is it possible to have the entries made in the gridview itself? I need to fetch entries from DB and after the user is done, the gridview entries will be stored again in the DB.

Please note that my app is WPF but for ease I have used Windows Form for just this Window.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17318/Add-Edit-and-Delete-in-DataGridView-with-Paging and http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=132 might help

Comment: Which event should I use for the DataGridView if i want to capture change in text of a cell? Just like for a textBox we have TextChanged()

Comment: there is an event cellvaluechanged event try that

Comment: watch this too http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19735/DataGridView-with-Detail-Edit-Form-VS-2005

Comment: that executes only after cell value is changed and we move to the next cell!

Comment: What do you mean by 'When the user is done/upon entering the last value' do you mean when they have finished editing a cell, when the cell is validated?